# howto concatenate two strings as a file name in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have three types(type1, type2, and type3) of content of text file stored in a subdirectory, and few prefixes for each type of files, e.g.: prefix1, prefix2,..., prefixN. File name is concatenated by prefix+type, e.g.: prefix1type1 for a specific file stored in that subdirectory.

What I'd like to do is to get user input and concatenate user's input with three types into a whole file name, and test it, if the file exists, then read its content to an array.

```
mapfile -t mytype1 < <( cat ./cpu/{$cpu}+type1 )
mapfile -t mytype2 < <( cat ./cpu/{$cpu}+type2 )
mapfile -t mytype3 < <( cat ./cpu/{$cpu}+type3 )
```

Does it work? I haven't try this, any idea? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: $cpu is what user inputted or selected.

Comment: What's the question here exactly?

Comment: shell doesn't have any special string concatenation operators, just do `cat ./cpu/${cpu}type1` -- note the `$` *outside* the braces

Comment: Thank you very much Glenn Jackman, I bet it should work, how am I able to give you credits? The part of project I'm working on is to create a shell script to install Gentoo automatically. I'm a newbie in terms of shell script, and I'm sure there are still problems ahead, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
for type in CFLAGS CHOST CPU ; do
    mapfile -t "$type" < ./cpu/"$cpu$type"
done
```

Comment: these types don't have such feature for loop, actually, they are CFLAGS, CHOST, CPU.